# Wordpress Magnifying function using images from custom filed "et_gallery"

Tags: php, wordpress, jquery-plugins, fancybox, custom-fields

The goal effect is: When clicked on the magnifying icon, it uses the "Fancybox" plugin to display big size images (mutiple images separated by commas) in the custom filed "et_gallery".

Right now the magnifying isn't working at all.
http://heidixu.com/#!/?page_id=4

It was working fine once. And then I accidently replaced the final code with an earlier version. So the version I currently have is pretty close but something is not right or missing and I can't figure out what because I'm not an expert in php...

This is the page: http://heidixu.com/#!/?page_id=4 and every other pages with thumbnails work the same.

This is my current version of php code that was edited:

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Portfolio Page
*/
?>
<?php 
$et_ptemplate_settings = array();
$et_ptemplate_settings = maybe_unserialize( get_post_meta($post->ID,'et_ptemplate_settings',true) );

$fullwidth = true;
$et_ptemplate_showtitle = isset( $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_showtitle'] ) ? (bool) $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_showtitle'] : false;
$et_ptemplate_showdesc = isset( $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_showdesc'] ) ? (bool) $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_showdesc'] : false;
$et_ptemplate_detect_portrait = isset( $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_detect_portrait'] ) ? (bool) $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_detect_portrait'] : false;

$gallery_cats = isset( $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_gallerycats'] ) ? (array) $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_gallerycats'] : array();
$et_ptemplate_gallery_perpage = isset( $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_gallery_perpage'] ) ? (int) $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_gallery_perpage'] : 12;

$et_ptemplate_portfolio_size = isset( $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_imagesize'] ) ? (int) $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_imagesize'] : 2;

$et_ptemplate_portfolio_class = '';
if ( $et_ptemplate_portfolio_size == 1 ) $et_ptemplate_portfolio_class = ' et_portfolio_small';
if ( $et_ptemplate_portfolio_size == 3 ) $et_ptemplate_portfolio_class = ' et_portfolio_large';
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="single_container et_shadow">
    <div class="single_content">
        <div class="entry post clearfix">
            <?php get_template_part('loop','page'); ?>
            <div id="et_pt_portfolio_gallery" class="clearfix<?php echo $et_ptemplate_portfolio_class; ?>">
                <?php $gallery_query = '';
                $portfolio_count = 1;
                $et_open_row = false;
                if ( !empty($gallery_cats) ) $gallery_query = '&cat=' . implode(",", $gallery_cats);
                else echo '<!-- gallery category is not selected -->'; ?>
                <?php 
                    $et_paged = is_front_page() ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : get_query_var( 'paged' );
                ?>
                <?php query_posts("showposts=$et_ptemplate_gallery_perpage&paged=" . $et_paged . $gallery_query); ?>
                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php $width = 260;
                    $height = 170;

                    if ( $et_ptemplate_portfolio_size == 1 ) {
                        $width = 140;
                        $height = 94;
                        $et_portrait_height = 170;
                    }
                    if ( $et_ptemplate_portfolio_size == 2 ) $et_portrait_height = 315;
                    if ( $et_ptemplate_portfolio_size == 3 ) {
                        $width = 430;
                        $height = 283;
                        $et_portrait_height = 860;
                    }                       

                    $et_auto_image_detection = false;
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) && $et_ptemplate_detect_portrait ) {
                        $wordpress_thumbnail = get_post( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
                        $wordpress_thumbnail_url = $wordpress_thumbnail->guid;

                        if ( et_is_portrait($wordpress_thumbnail_url) ) $height = $et_portrait_height;
                    }

                    $titletext = get_the_title();
                    $et_portfolio_title = get_post_meta($post->ID,'et_portfolio_title',true) ? get_post_meta($post->ID,'et_portfolio_title',true) : get_the_title();
                    $et_videolink = get_post_meta($post->ID,'et_videolink',true) ? get_post_meta($post->ID,'et_videolink',true) : '';

                    $thumbnail = get_thumbnail($width,$height,'',$titletext,$titletext,true,'et_portfolio');
                    $thumb = $thumbnail["thumb"];

                    if ( $et_ptemplate_detect_portrait && $thumbnail["use_timthumb"] && et_is_portrait($thumb) ) {
                        $height = $et_portrait_height;
                    } ?>

                    <?php if ( $portfolio_count == 1 || ( $et_ptemplate_portfolio_size == 2 && (!$fullwidth && ($portfolio_count+1) % 2 == 0) ) || ( $et_ptemplate_portfolio_size == 3 && (($portfolio_count+1) % 2 == 0) ) ) {
                        $et_open_row = true; ?>
                        <div class="et_pt_portfolio_row clearfix">
                    <?php } ?>

                            <div class="et_pt_portfolio_item">
                                <?php if ($et_ptemplate_showtitle) { ?>
                                    <h2 class="et_pt_portfolio_title"><?php echo $et_portfolio_title; ?></h2>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <div class="et_pt_portfolio_entry<?php if ( $height == $et_portrait_height ) echo ' et_portrait_layout'; ?>">
                                    <div class="et_pt_portfolio_image<?php if ($et_videolink <> '') echo ' et_video'; ?>">
                                        <?php print_thumbnail($thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $titletext, $width, $height, ''); ?>

                                        <?php $gallery = explode(',', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'et_gallery', true));
foreach ($gallery as $item) { ?>
<a class="fancybox" href="<?php echo $item; ?>" style="display: none;" rel="gallery[<?php echo $post->ID; ?>]" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"></a>
<?php } ?>

                                        <span class="et_pt_portfolio_overlay"></span>

                                        <a class="et_portfolio_zoom_icon <?php if ($et_videolink <> '') echo 'et_video_lightbox'; else echo('fancybox'); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"<?php if ($et_videolink == '') echo ' rel="gallery[' . $post->ID . '"]'; ?> href="<?php if ($et_videolink <> '') echo $et_videolink; else echo($thumbnail['fullpath']); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Zoom in','Sky'); ?></a>
                                        <a class="et_portfolio_more_icon" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Read more','Sky'); ?></a>
                                    </div> <!-- end .et_pt_portfolio_image -->
                                </div> <!-- end .et_pt_portfolio_entry -->
                                <?php if ($et_ptemplate_showdesc) { ?>
                                    <p><?php truncate_post(90); ?></p>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div> <!-- end .et_pt_portfolio_item -->

                    <?php if ( ($et_ptemplate_portfolio_size == 2 && !$fullwidth && $portfolio_count % 2 == 0) || ( $et_ptemplate_portfolio_size == 3 && ($portfolio_count % 2 == 0) ) ) {
                        $et_open_row = false; ?>
                        </div> <!-- end .et_pt_portfolio_row -->
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php if ( ($et_ptemplate_portfolio_size == 2 && $fullwidth && $portfolio_count % 3 == 0) || ($et_ptemplate_portfolio_size == 1 && !$fullwidth && $portfolio_count % 3 == 0) || ($et_ptemplate_portfolio_size == 1 && $fullwidth && $portfolio_count % 5 == 0) ) { ?>
                        </div> <!-- end .et_pt_portfolio_row -->
                        <div class="et_pt_portfolio_row clearfix">
                        <?php $et_open_row = true; ?>
                    <?php } ?>

                <?php $portfolio_count++; 
                endwhile; ?>
                    <?php if ( $et_open_row ) { 
                        $et_open_row = false; ?>
                        </div> <!-- end .et_pt_portfolio_row -->
                    <?php } ?>
                    <div class="page-nav clearfix">
                        <?php if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); }
                        else { ?>
                             <?php get_template_part('includes/navigation'); ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div> <!-- end .entry -->
                <?php else : ?>
                    <?php if ( $et_open_row ) { 
                        $et_open_row = false; ?>
                        </div> <!-- end .et_pt_portfolio_row -->
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php get_template_part('includes/no-results'); ?>
                <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

                <?php if ( $et_open_row ) { 
                    $et_open_row = false; ?>
                    </div> <!-- end .et_pt_portfolio_row -->
                <?php } ?>
            </div> <!-- end #et_pt_portfolio_gallery -->
        </div> <!-- end .entry -->
    </div> <!-- end .single_content -->
    <div class="content-bottom"></div>
</div> <!-- end .single_container -->

<?php if (get_option('sky_show_pagescomments') == 'on') comments_template('', true); ?>
```

Could any php experts please take a look. Thank you so much.

-Heidi

Answer (score 0):

So far, when you click on the magnifying icon, it produces this error:

```
Error: a is undefined
Source File: http://heidixu.com/wp-content/themes/Sky/epanel/page_templates/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js?ver=1.3.4
Line: 19
```

It looks like the link (the `<a>` tag) is not bound to fancybox regardless it has the specified class.

I want to believe that your generated code is not well formed; you have this html:

```
<a href="http://heidixu.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/x3_big.jpg" ]="" rel="gallery[63" title="X3 Network" class="et_portfolio_zoom_icon fancybox" style="opacity: 0; display: inline;">Zoom in</a>
```

and wonder if this part specifically

```
... ]="" rel="gallery[ ....
```

...is creating the error.  I cannot find what part of your php code generates those (misplaced?) brackets.

Comment: So that part is fixed. <?php if ($et_videolink == '') echo ' rel="gallery[' . $post->ID . '"]'; ?> the bracket is now closed before the double quote. But it still wouldn't display the big images.

Comment: you cannot have an attribute enclosed in brackets like [rel=gallery[63]] because now it produces: 
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [rel=gallery[63]]
Source File: http://heidixu.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1
Line: 3

Comment: I guess you want rel="gallery63" rather than rel="gallery[63]" but the way you open/close your brackets is actually producing [rel=gallery[63]]

Comment: Thanks JFK, this code I provided probably needs more work than I thought to get it work properly like I described in the goal. Not being an expert in php, I'm willing to pay for someone to complete this now. Are you familiar with Wordpress at all? Do you think you'll be able to tackle this task?

Comment: @kikix2125 sure I can help. Drop me a line here http://picssel.com/contact so we can talk